# If all in list == something

Tags: python, python-2.6

Using Python 2.6, is there a way to check if all the items of a sequence equals a given value, in one statement?

```
[pseudocode]
my_sequence = (2,5,7,82,35)

if all the values in (type(i) for i in my_sequence) == int:
     do()
```

Instead of, say:

```
my_sequence = (2,5,7,82,35)
all_int = True
for i in my_sequence:
    if type(i) is not int:
        all_int = False
        break

if all_int:
    do()
```

Comment: Can somebody edit this so that "my_squence" is spelled consistently throughout?  my_squence != my_sequence  Thanks.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use:

```
all( type(i) is int for i in lst )
```

Example:

```
In [1]: lst = range(10)
In [2]: all( type(i) is int for i in lst )
Out[2]: True
In [3]: lst.append('steve')
In [4]: all( type(i) is int for i in lst )
Out[4]: False
```

[Edit]. Made cleaner as per comments.

Comment: When comparing types, always use "is"!

Answer (score 15):

Do you mean

```
all( type(i) is int for i in my_list )
```

?

Edit:  Changed to `is`.  Slightly faster.

Comment: @ S.Lott: thinking negation, will `any( type(i) != int for i in my_lst )` be more efficient? or the same over an average number of cases?

Comment: Both any and all are efficient, meaning the stop iterating once they find a True or False value respectively.

Comment: @JV: all == and any != are the same over an average number of cases.

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest:

```
if all(isinstance(i, int) for i in my_list):
```

[`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) first appeared in 2006 with [Python 2.5 (feature implemented by Raymond Hettinger)](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.5.html#other-language-changes).
If you're using an older version of Python, the links provide sample implementations.

I also suggest using [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) since it will also catch subclasses of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness I thought I would add the fact that NumPy's 'all' is different from the built-in 'all'. If for example running Python through Python(x,y), NumPy is loaded automatically (and cannot be unloaded as far as I know), so when trying to run the above code it produces rather unexpected results:

```
>>> if (all(v == 0 for v in [0,1])):
...     print 'this should not happen'
... this should not happen
```

More information on this is in Stack Overflow question *[numpy all differing from builtin all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391501/numpy-all-differing-from-builtin-all)*. As a solution you can either surround the generator with brackets to produce a list:

```
>>> all( [v == 0 for v in [0,1]] )
False
```

Or call the built-in function explicitly:

```
>>> __builtins__.all(v == 0 for v in [0,1,'2'])
False
```

I found a way to stop Spyder from importing NumPy per default:
*[Spyder default module import list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400993/spyder-default-module-import-list)*