# Spyder default module import list

Tags: python, import, module, spyder

I'm trying to set up a slightly customised version of Spyder.  When Spyder starts, it automatically imports a long list of modules, including things from matplotlib, numpy, scipy etc.  Is there a way to add my own modules to that list?

In case it makes a difference, I'm using the Spyder configuration provided by the Python(X,Y) Windows installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The startup script for Spyder is in `site-packages/spyderlib/scientific_startup.py`.

Carlos' answer would also work, but this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 18):

First you have to create a Python file with the modules you want to import at startup. Suppose you call it `my_imports.py` and that it has this contents:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then you have to go to

`Tools > Preferences > IPython Console > Startup > Run a file`

select the option

`Use the following file`

and finally click on the button to the right of text field below that option to select your `my_imports.py` file.

Answer (score -2):

If Spyder is executed as a python script by python binary, then you should be able to simply edit Spyder python sources and include the modules you need. You should take a look into how is it actually executed upon start.

Comment: This amounts to "go read the source code" and is not an answer to the question!