# How to check if a list ONLY contains a certain item

Tags: python, list

I have a list called bag. I want to be able to check if only a particular item is in it.

```
bag = ["drink"]
if only "drink" in bag:
    print 'There is only a drink in the bag'
else:
    print 'There is something else other than a drink in the bag'
```

Of course, where I put 'only' in the code there, it is wrong. Is there any simple replacement of that? I have tried a few similar words.

Comment: if len(bag) == 1 and item in bag:

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear here, but do you mean that the list has only one item and it is "drink", or just that "drink" is in the list? In other words, would ["drink", "candy bar"] pass your if only test?

Comment: You don't try "a few similar words" to do something in a programming language, but what you do is learn the basics of the language first, and then use your knowledge to do stuff. That's the natural process of learning.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ monte-carlo search for keywords that do what you want, that isn't how you program? You're missing out

Comment: @en_Knight Sorry but I failed to understand what you mean.

Comment: Possible dup. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405516/if-all-in-list-something and Shadowfax just a joke (randomly guess words until sometihng works)

Comment: @en_Knight I thought so to myself, I was just being cautious :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the builtin `all()` function.

```
if bag and all(elem == "drink" for elem in bag):
    print("Only 'drink' is in the bag")
```

The `all()` function is as follows:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

For this reason, an empty list will return True. Since there are no elements, it will skip the loop entirely and return True. Because this is the case, you must add an explicit `and len(bag)` or `and bag` to ensure that the bag is not empty (`()` and `[]` are false-like).

Also, you could use a `set`.

```
if set(bag) == {['drink']}:
    print("Only 'drink' is in the bag")
```

Or, similarly:

```
if len(set(bag)) == 1 and 'drink' in bag:
    print("Only 'drink' is in the bag")
```

All of these will work with 0 or more elements in the list.

Comment: The first one is the only one that short circuits if there is something else in the bag (all good answers)

Comment: @en_Knight That's true.

Comment: @en_Knight Good catch. I replaced it with `any` and `!=` which will not fail on an empty list :)

Comment: for the any one you need to use if not, because the one you have there is true if any element does NOT equal drink

Comment: (Or at least I assume your elem was short for element anyway)

Comment: Hmm... Actually, this will still fail on an empty list. I suppose the only way is to add an explicit `and len(bag)`

Comment: Looks good +1. I'd switch it so the and statement is first (for short circuiting again) but doesn't matter much

Answer (score 1):

You could directly check for equality with a list that only contains this item:

```
if bag == ["drink"]:
    print 'There is only a drink in the bag'
else:
    print 'There is something else other than a drink in the bag'
```

Alternatively if you want to check whether the lists contains any number greater than zero of the same item `"drink"`, you can count them and compare with the list length:

```
if bag.count("drink") == len(bag) > 0:
    print 'There are only drinks in the bag'
else:
    print 'There is something else other than a drink in the bag'
```

Comment: Sam question as Lafada's - what about ["drink","drink"] ? Doesn't that qualfiy as having only drink in it?

Comment: Not sure. It isn't clearly described in the question. But I added an alternative for that as well.

Comment: ok that second one seems almost right. Just to be pedantic, it fails on the empty list though

Comment: ["drink","drink"] would indeed qualify as only having drink. I just realised that I wasn't clear in the question. The second one works best

Comment: the second works best to test if there is nothing else, but as @ByteCommander indirectly pointed out `[].count("drink") == len([])` does evaluate as True.

Comment: @en_Knight I corrected the second example and added a check that the length must be greater than zero. Now the empty list is no longer a false positive.

Comment: and it doesn't have the double negative needed for `not any(elem != "drink" for elem in bag)` to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can check length of list

```
if len(bag) == 1 and "drink" in bag:
    #do your operation.
```

Comment: It seems like ['drink','drink'] should qualify as only having drink in it, but doesn't in your implementatino

Comment: yes you are right :), then have to check `all` second answer :)