# Filter nested list based on value of sub-list

Tags: python, matlab, indexing

so this question is quite complicated to explain.
Say I have a list of list of list of grades and a name, for example:

```
    a=[[90,50,40],'Josh']
    b=[[85,60,90],'Becky']
    c=[a,b]
```

so that c would be:

```
    c=[[[90,50,40],'Josh'],[[85,60,90],'Becky']]
```

now let's say the list is much longer and I'm interested in a student who got a list of grades of [100,100,100]. How can I loop over that?

From my usage of MATLAB I know I used c[:][0] to get a "list" of the grades.

Now I'd like to do something as:

```
   target=[100,100,100]
   if target in c[:][0]:
   print 'we got a smart fella in the hood'
```

how can I do that in python? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if all in list == something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405516/if-all-in-list-something)

Comment: You should iterate through the list and check every list, if there is your targeted list

Comment: In Python, `c[:]` is only a copy of  the list `c`, so `c[:][0]` is only `c[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be iterating like:

```
c = [[[90,50,40],'Josh'],[[85,60,90],'Becky'], [[100,100,100],'Mano']]
target = [100,100,100]

for grade, name in c:
    if grade == target:
        print name
```

which will print:

```
Mano
```

If you want the list of all the name satisfying the mentioned criterion, you may use a *list comprehension* expression as:

```
names = [name for grade, name in c if grade == target]
```

Comment: `all(score == 100 for score in grade)` makes this no longer dependent on the lists having exactly three scores.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know of the all() method, nor the possibility of using two values to iterate on.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the matrix **c** would appear as a nested list structure.  Digging down the levels ...

```
c[1] is [[85,60,90],'Becky']
c[1][0] is [85,60,90]
c[1][0][2] is 60
```

That should explain the naming to you.  Now, you need to check the scores lists, c[*][0] for the target values.  If you need an exact match, it's easy enough: build a temporary list of the values and report if there's a hit.

```
if target in [record[0] for record in c]:
    print "Smart person exists"
```

If you need to print a list of the names, try

```
print [record[1] for record in c if record[0] == target]
```

Does that get you moving?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going a class-based approach to get away from nested lists

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self, name, scores):
        self.name = name
        self.scores = scores

    def has_perfect_scores():
        return all(score == 100 for score in self.scores)
```

Then,

```
c = [ Student('Josh', [90,50,40]), Student('Becky', [85,60,90]) ]
for student in c:
    if student.has_perfect_scores():
        print 'we got a smart fella in the hood named {}'.format(student.name)
```

For any student you can loop over their `scores` list

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of using classes and perhaps I should.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only to know if there is a match, you can do:

```
c=[[[90,50,40],'Josh'],[[85,60,90],'Becky']]
target = [85,60,90]
if target in [i[0] for i in c]:
    print "true"
```