# Iterating through a dictionary and a list within

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have a dictionary example as:

```
dictionary = {Bay1: [False,False,True],
        Bay2: [True,True,True],
        Bay3: [True,True,False],
        Bay4: [False,False,False] }
```

What I'm trying to do is to go through the dictionary by checking each bay (Bay1, Bay2...) to see which one has an array where everything inside it is `False`. For that example, I want it to return `'Bay4'`.

Secondly, I want to be able to check to see which is `False` and which is `True` in each bay by using loops. In other words, you can imagine that `True` represents being 'Booked' and `False` represents being free or 'Not booked'. I want to be able to check that for each bay and present it to the user in a good and easily readable format.

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried so far. For first question [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405516/if-all-in-list-something)

Answer (score 0):

You should provide some more information.

Anyway, if I understood your problem, you can use `any()` and `all()` in a `for` loop:

```
# print all Bay with all False:
for key, value in mydict:
    if not any(value):
        print key

# print all Bay with at least 1 False:
for key, value in mydict:
    if not all(value):
        print key
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** **part**

Returning key having value all `False`:

```
>>> d = {'Bay1': [False,False,True],
     'Bay2': [True,True,True],
     'Bay3': [True,True,False],
     'Bay4': [False,False,False]}

>>> ' '.join([k for k, v in d.items() if any(v) is False])
Bay4
```

**Second** **part**

Counting number of `True` (booked) and `False` (not booked) for each `bay`:

```
>>> d = {'Bay1': [False,False,True],
         'Bay2': [True,True,True],
         'Bay3': [True,True,False],
         'Bay4': [False,False,False]}

>>> '\n'.join(['{}: {} booked and {} not booked'.format(k, v.count(True), v.count(False)) for k, v in d.items()])
Bay1: 1 booked and 2 not booked                                
Bay2: 3 booked and 0 not booked                             
Bay3: 2 booked and 1 not booked                             
Bay4: 0 booked and 3 not booked
```